# Finding the inverse Laplace of this function $\frac{1}{\left({s}^{2}+{1}\right)^{2}}$.

Tags: laplace-transform

Finding the inverse Laplace transform of

$L^{-1}\left( \dfrac {1}{\left( x+1\right) ^{2}}\right)$

I understnd that the inverse laplace of

$L^{-1}\left(\dfrac {1}{\left( x+1\right) }\right)$

Is equal to the negative exponent of x

$e^{-x}$

But cant seem to see the intuition into finding the inverse laplace function of the function I have given

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\mathcal L\left\{t^{n} e^{-\alpha t} \cdot u(t)\right\}&=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}t^{n} e^{-\alpha t}\mathrm d t=\int_0^\infty e^{-(s+\alpha)t}t^{n} \mathrm d t\\
&=\frac{1}{(s+\alpha)^{n+1}}\int_0^\infty e^{-u}u^{n} \mathrm d u=\frac{1}{(s+\alpha)^{n+1}}\Gamma(n+1)\\
&=\frac{n!}{(s+\alpha)^{n+1}}
\end{align}
So you have that
$$
\mathcal L^{-1}\left\{\frac{1}{(x+1)^{2}}\right\}=t e^{-t} \cdot u(t)
$$

Another way is
$$
\mathcal L\left\{e^{-\alpha t} \cdot u(t)\right\}=\frac{1}{s+\alpha}
$$
and using the property $ (-1)^{n} F^{(n)}(s) =\mathcal L\left\{t^n f(t)\right\}$
we have
$$\mathcal L\left\{t e^{-\alpha t} \cdot u(t)\right\}=(-1)\left(\frac{1}{s+\alpha}\right)'=\frac{1}{(s+\alpha)^2}$$