# Inverse Laplace transform of $\frac 1 {(s^2+1)^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, convolution

How to find the inverse Laplace of:

$$f(t) = 2\Bigg[\mathscr{L}^{-1}\bigg(\frac{-1}{(s^2+1)^2}\bigg) + \mathscr{L}^{-1}\bigg(\frac{3}{s^2+1}\bigg) \Bigg]$$

$$f(t) = 2\Bigg[\mathscr{L}^{-1}\bigg(\frac{-1}{(s^2+1)^2}\bigg) + 3sin(t) \Bigg]$$

$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\bigg(\frac{-1}{(s^2+1)^2}\bigg) = ?$$

Comment: $$\frac{1}{(s^2+\omega^2)^2} = \frac{1}{(s^2+\omega^2)}\frac{1}{(s^2+\omega^2)} \longleftrightarrow sin(\omega t) * sin(\omega t)$$  would this make sense??  I just made up this transform based on convolution theorem

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1743662/finding-the-inverse-laplace-of-this-function-frac1-lefts21-right

Comment: I suppose I could also find the inverse transform using the definition of inverse laplace transform: $f(t) = \frac{1}{2 \pi j}~ \lim \limits_{T \to \infty}~ \int \limits^{\alpha + jT}_{\alpha - jT} e^{st}~ F(s)~ ds$.  But, that's a little bit heavy handed...

Comment: Can you **also** use a [*Table of Laplace Transforms*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/laplace_table.pdf)? From item $11$, we have $$f(t) = \dfrac{1}{2} \left (\sin t - t \cos t \right)$$

Comment: I would gladly use a Table of Laplace transforms... is that one in a table?

Comment: thanks...didn't know about those ones...

Answer (score 3):

Since $\frac{1}{s^2+1}=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac{1}{s-i}-\frac{1}{s+i}\right)$,$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{(s^2+1)^2}&=-\frac14\left(\frac{1}{(s-i)^2}+\frac{1}{(s+i)^2}-\frac{2}{s^2+1}\right)\\&=-\frac14[(s-i)^{-2}-(s+i)^{-2}]+\frac{1}{4i}\left(\frac{1}{s-i}-\frac{1}{s+i}\right),\end{align}$$which has inverse Laplace transform$$-\frac14[te^{it}+te^{-it}]+\frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{4i}=-\frac12t\cos t+\frac12\sin t.$$

Comment: interesting technique.   but, i think maybe its easier to perform convolution in the time by covolving sin with sin... messy complex algebra vs. messy calculus integrals... its kind of a toss up...

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to consider:
$$\frac 1 {(s^2+1)^2}=\frac {1}{2s}\frac {2s} {(s^2+1)^2}$$
We have:
$$\frac {2s} {(s^2+1)^2}=-1 \left (\frac {1} {(s^2+1)} \right )'$$
$$\frac {2s} {(s^2+1)^2}=-\frac d {ds}\{\mathcal {L}\{\sin(t)\}\}=\mathcal {L}\{t\sin(t)\}$$
Then use Convolution theorem:
$$\mathcal {L^{-1}}\left\{\frac 1 {(s^2+1)^2}\right \}=\frac {1}{2}*t\sin (t)$$
The Convolution integral is easier to evaluate.

$$f(t)=\frac 1 2\int_0^t \tau \sin(\tau) d \tau$$
$$f(t)=\frac 12 (\sin(t)-t\cos(t))$$
$$\boxed {\mathcal {L^{-1}}\left\{\frac 1 {(s^2+1)^2}\right \}=\frac 12 (\sin(t)-t\cos(t))}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$g(t) = sin(t) * \sin(t)$$

$$g(t) = \frac{1}{2}\int \limits_{0}^{t} 2\sin(\tau) \sin(t - \tau) d\tau$$

Applying trig identity:

$$2\sin(A)\sin(B)=\cos(A-B)-cos(A+B)$$

we have:

$$g(t) = \frac{1}{2}\int \limits_{0}^{t} \Big[\cos(\tau -(t-\tau)) - \cos(\tau +t - \tau)\Big]d\tau$$

$$g(t) = \frac{1}{2}\int \limits_{0}^{t} \Big[\cos(-t+2\tau) - \cos(t)\Big]d\tau$$

$$g(t) = \frac{1}{2}\int \limits_{0}^{t}\cos(2\tau-t)~d\tau - \frac{1}{2}\cos(t)\int \limits_{0}^{t} ~d\tau$$

$$g(t) = \frac{1}{4}\bigg[ \sin(2\tau-t)\bigg]^{t}_{0}- \frac{1}{2}\cos(t)\bigg[\tau\bigg]^{t}_{0}$$

$$g(t) = \frac{1}{4}\bigg[ \sin(2\tau-t)\bigg]^{t}_{0} - \frac{1}{2}\cos(t)\bigg[\tau\bigg]^{t}_{0}$$

$$g(t) = \frac{1}{4}\bigg[ \sin(2t-t) - \sin(0-t)\bigg] - \frac{1}{2}t \cos(t)$$

$$g(t) = \frac{1}{4}\bigg[ \sin(t) + \sin(t)\bigg] - \frac{1}{2}t \cos(t)$$

$$g(t) = \frac{1}{4}\bigg[ 2\sin(t)\bigg] - \frac{1}{2}t \cos(t)$$

$$g(t) = \frac{1}{2}\sin(t) - \frac{1}{2}t \cos(t)$$